# Nothing said before "but" really counts

Tags: meaning

My boyfriend sent a message.

- Nothing someone says before the word 'But' really counts.

What is the meaning of the above sentence?

Comment: If your boyfriend said: "I'd really love to go to the movies with you But I've an assignment to complete by tonight." it'd  mean he isn't going to movies with you. May be this is what he meant.

Comment: Your boyfriend is paraphrasing a very popular TV show at you. The meaning is that a nice thing said before a "but" can easily be completely fake and intended only to soften the blow of a non-nice thing that came after the "but".

Comment: I want to help you, but I'm busy. [So I won't help you. The *want* part is meaningless.]

Comment: Hello, Gow. I don't understand your question. Are the words that your boyfriend wrote "Nothing someone says before a word 'But' it really couts"? Could you recheck your spelling to confirm that those are the exact words from his message? Thanks.

Comment: yes those are exact words Sven Yargs.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it has nothing to do with English. No idioms or puns or anything English-specific involved. Translate the line word for word into your mother tongue, and you will have the answer.

Comment: Oh, and they are your boyfriend, for crying out loud. Just text them back, "what do you mean?"

Answer (score 4):

I want to answer your question, but I'm not sure you want to hear it.

My password is 1234567, but please don't give that out to anyone else.

I killed him, in cold blood, and I'd do it again on a dare, but enough about me.  How are you doing?

The messages meaning refers to how *sometimes* people use but to take back what they've already said.  It over generalizes this into *always* most likely for the dramatic effect.  The examples above progressively shows how wrong this idea can be.

But you knew that already right? ;)